# Pass variable of unix timestamp into date object - google API direction request

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a dropdown list featuring a set of fixtures each with a specific date. The select id is set to ="dateofgame" and the value of each fixture option is set as a 'epoch Timestamp in milliseconds' for example "1491660000000".

**HTML**

```
<select id="dateofgame">
<option value="1491660000000">Sat 8th April - Cheltenham Town 3PM</option>
<option value="1492178400000">Fri 14th Apil - Mansfield Town 3PM</option>
<option value="1492869600000">Sat 22th April - Doncaster Rovers 3PM</option>
<option value="1494088200000">Sat 6th May - Cambridge United 5.30PM</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to pass the timestamp value of the fixture selected to a directions request using Google's Javascript API.

I have set this up as followed:

**Javascipt**

```
document.getElementById('dateofgame').addEventListener('change', function() {
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pos);
});
```

and then

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pos) {
var selectedDate = document.getElementById('dateofgame').value;
```

followed by

```
 directionsService.route({
  origin: pos,
  destination: {lat: *VALUE*,lng: *VALUE*},
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
   transitOptions: {
   modes: ['RAIL'],
//       arrivalTime: new Date(1491660000000),
   arrivalTime: new Date(selectedDate),
   routingPreference: 'FEWER_TRANSFERS'
},
```

The problem I have here is if I pass the variable 'selectedDate' from whichever option has been selected with the timestamp value it isn't working. However, if I explicitly define the timestamp (commented out line above) - the API request will route for that date.

Anyone able to tell me why the same value isn't working if I pass it as a variable?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the problem here is when you pass the selectedDate to the date constructor it's default return is not a unix error string. 

You should use new Date(selectedDate).getTime()

Comment: Have tried this didn't work just got 'InvalidValueError: in property transitOptions: in property arrivalTime: not a Date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"arrivalTime: new Date(parseInt(selectedDate))," - this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does the API expect a unix epoch string or does it expect a formatted date string?

```
console.log(new Date(1491660000000)); // Sun Apr 09 2017 02:00:00 GMT+1200 (NZST)
```

Why don't you just send the selectedDate without wrapping it a in a date constructor?

```
arrivalTime: selectedDate
```

Comment: I've tried that doesn't work, just get 'InvalidValueError: in property transitOptions: in property arrivalTime: not a Date' & the API expects a unix epoch string I believe

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

The link above specifies that it expects the unix epoch to be in seconds not miliseconds. 

Can you divide your current values by 1000 and try again.

Comment: It doesn't work in seconds only milliseconds have tried that previous. I have since found the solution needed: "arrivalTime: new Date(parseInt(selectedDate)),"